# When registering my application with Growl, how can I define what notification style to use in the .growlRegDict file?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, growl

I would like to force growl to use the Bezel style notification for all notifications in my application.

Considering a typical .growlRegDict looks something like the example below, is there a key/value that I can define in my application's .growlRegDict file that will set the default style for my application to the Bezel style.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-    1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>TicketVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>AllNotifications</key>
    <array>
        <string>MyNotification</string>
    </array>
    <key>DefaultNotifications</key>
    <array>
        <string>MyNotification</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

After posting to the Growl Google group, I've found out that defining the alert style for your own application is not possible.  Whatever the end user has configured as their preferred alert style overall or for each particular application is the style that will be used.